# List all combinations of 4 operators and 4 numbers then test their final value C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, operators, combinations

I'm trying to make a 24 solver (the game 24's objective is to use +,-,*,/ to get to the number 24)

I'm reasonably confident that the only way to do this is using a brute force method (try each combination of the numbers with the operators in between them.

To eliminate the need for parenthesis, I think the number placement should also be randomized.

I want to do this in C#.

How should I go about doing this?
(basic outline, plan...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from: [google codeplex](http://code.google.com/p/solve24game/)

> Algorithm
>   1. Think 24 game result as a binary tree(if you don't know what's it, check data structure book first).
>   2. There are 3 types of binary branches. "D OP D", "P OP D or D OP P", "P OP P". In which, D is digit(integer larger than 1), P is pointer to another downstream branch, and OP is operator "+,-,,/". Especially, "D OP D" must be in the leaf position of the tree.
>   3. Generate all the possible trees. And apply some optimization, like element at the two sides of "+," are switchable, while "-,/" are not.
>   4. Generate all the possible permutation of 4 digits (4! = 24). And remove the same copies.
>   5. Mix trees and digits permutations, do calculation, and we get the result!

Comment: Doesn't "[google](http://code.google.com/)" and "[codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/)" contradict itself? ;-)

Comment: @dtb hmm, afaict 90% of all code is written using google and codeplex

Comment: The algorithm is language agnostic, a binary tree is a data structure.

Comment: I;m trying to learn c#.  I'm not looking for the most efficient, i'm looking for what I can do using c#

Comment: If you are learning then applying this algorithm should be a good lesson.

Comment: Let us know I'd you get stuck

Comment: Sure.  With over 3K rep, I'm sure you know what your doing.